# i not get second body on world in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

```
  Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>(world.getBodyCount());
                world.getBodies();

                for (Body body : bodies) {

                    update(body); 

                }
```

Comment: Which is it? Java, C++ or C?

Comment: @AndyTurner not C for sure :p

Comment: ... and `Array<Body> bodies = new ...` is also not C++, so probably Java. @kalpesh please note that this site is for questions and answers and not for language guessing quizzes ;)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, first you're allocating an `Array` and ensuring the backing array will fit `world.getBodyCount()`. So, if the existing number of bodies in your world is ten, the `ArrayList` will have enough memory allocated to store ten bodies initially, but all of these entries will be `null`.

Then you call `world.getBodies()`; but this has no access to the local variable `bodies`, it's definitely not `static`; therefore your `Array` is still left uninitialized!

The `Array` is empty when you come to the `for` loop, so it execues zero times; nothing gets updated. So; the real trick is you're not accessing the `bodies` contained within the world properly.

Does `getBodies()` return a `List` you should be using instead?